# Compiling C# Code in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, csharpcodeprovider

I have using the built in CSharpCodeProvider class in previous C# .NET projects and it has worked great. I see this has been removed in UWP. I've been banging my head against the wall trying to figure out if there is a way. I can't seem to find any scrap of information. But, I did come across an interesting app called #Code by Shahul Hameed on the Windows Store. This software claims to be able to compile code and be able to run it, and indeed it does. How are they achieving this, if such actions are not possible on the framework? Is it possible they're sending the code over the net to a web service of some kind and getting the returned console output? I thought so, but what about the live stdin support they've provided in the app, how would that work in a cloud compile situation?

Thanks for shedding any light

**Code on Windows Store:** https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/code/9nblggh4s3mf

Comment: is `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp` available in UWP? If yes then you can use `CSharpCompilation` which is the Roslyn infrastructure if I don't recall it wrong.

Comment: @Gusman It does not appear to be available from my trials.

Comment: It's a NuGet package, add it and it will work (tested and compiles fine).

Comment: The design-goal for UWP (WinRT actually) was to make Microsoft competitive in the mobile computing business.  Similar to how iOS is different from OSX.   Billions of dollars spent on it.  That phone that nobody wants to buy does not have a just-in-time compiler.  That contraption you are supposed to wear on your head doesn't either.  Ahead-of-time is important for such devices, called .NET Native.

Comment: @Gusman Ok this is trickier but it does seem to have a possibility. Except that by default it can't find any System namespace items. I'm going to have to study it some more.

Comment: IF you want I can add an example on how to compile a DLL with this namespace.

Comment: I believe you add it ot MetadataReference array. But the real question is, how to avoid adding like 20 different DLLs

Comment: I'm going to delete the answer, the compilation phase works but there's no way to load at runtime the libraries under UWP. Sorry :(